# Change a HREF with jQuery with a left mouse button click only for that single click

Tags: jquery, fancybox, href

I want to open a Site in an iframe with fancybox, if the user chooses to open the link to that site in a new tab or window, then a different layout(the complete layout) needs to be delivered.

The normal link brings up the full page, but if I add &type=77 to the end, my CMS knows that it should deliver the stripped down version that is suited for the iframe. The following code attaches the "&type=77" if the link is clicked with the left mouse button.

```
$('#mylink').mousedown(function(event) {
        if(event.which == 1) {
            var actualHref = $(this).attr("href");
            $(this).attr("href", actualHref + "&type=77");
        } 
    });
```

This works great, but it attaches the part for every click. So, if I left click once and close the fancybox and right click(open in new tab) afterwards, then I still end up with the new URL with the attached part. And it also attaches that part for every click.

I tried to use window.location to the changed url instead of changing the url - that worked partially, it brought up the right url but it broke the fancybox. The fancybox started loading but then it got redirected to the new page.

Maybe there's a much better approach for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Use the `.one` method:</strike>

```
$('#mylink').one("mousedown", function(event) {
        if(event.which == 1) {
            var actualHref = $(this).attr("href");
            $(this).attr("href", actualHref + "&type=77");
        } 
    });
```

**Update**
Fancy box can accept the href to open when you assign the plugin to the objects, so do something like this:

```
$("#mylink").each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.fancybox({"href": $this.attr("href")+"&type=77"});
});
```

(Some people might know a better way than/dislike using `each` for a single element, but I don't think it really matters for a single call)

Comment: I didn't know the one method but in this case, it doesn't seem to help much. - It adds the part but the added part stays, so for the next "open in new tab" that part is still there and it shouldnt be.

Comment: Ahh okay, I get what you need now, sorry, I kinda skimmed the question (bad habit!), I think you'll be better off doing it in the fancybox activation code, appending the type there, rather than change the physical href, whats your code for hooking into fancybox?

Comment: I need to change the href to let my CMS know, that it should serve another layout for that page. I just activate the fancybox like this $("#mylink").fancybox();

Comment: Thanky you Psy, it's working really well. I think this is the solution  for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solves the issue:

```
var myLink = $('#mylink');
        var actualHref = myLink.attr("href");

        myLink.one("mousedown", function (event) {
            if (event.which == 1) {
                $(this).attr("href", actualHref + "&type=77");
            }
        });
        myLink.one("mouseleave", function (event) {
            if (event.which == 1) {
                $(this).attr("href", actualHref);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Same Problem as with Psytronics answer. This only solves the problem, that the "&type=77" is not being added several times anymore.

Comment: Can you send a link. I find it hard to imagine what the problem is

Comment: I'm afraid i can't offer a link. The problem in short: I have link with an adress that ends like "index.php?id=59" and only for the case, when somebody does a normal left mouse click on it, that link should be altered and point to "index.php?id=59&type=77" - it should however stay the way it was in the source code.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts, but i think this isn't a usable solution. I testet it and it's somehow buggy, I don't quite understand why but it's not working reliably. - I'm not sure if Psytronics new solution is very well written code, just because i'm not very proficient in JS but it seems to do the job.  Thanks anyways!

Comment: I think what Psytronic suggest is better that you set the href with the one function from here and once the fancybox is opened then you remove the parameter from there

Comment: The good thing actually is, that you don't change the url itself and you don't have to change it back. It's an advanced option from fancybox that i didn't know: you can set the content source, hence the link stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery .one() method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to execute the event only once.

[jQuery .unbind() method](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove the event handler from the element.

You may also want to read more about mouse events:

[W3C Mouse Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents)

[Which vs Button](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button)